# How to set state using Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an array of objects like this :

```
var fruitsArray = [{ fruit: 'Apple', count: 0 },{fruit: 'Banana', count: 0 },{fruit: 'Grapes', count: 0}]
```

Now I have a button where I want to increase the count of every fruit whenever it's visible. So, every button press will increase the count value of respective fruits and store it.

Currently, I am doing :

```
 const [count, setCount] = useState(fruitsArray);

 const fruitsCount = () => {
      console.log(fruitsArray[selected].count += 1)
      setCount({
        ...fruitsArray,
        count : fruitsArray[selected].count + 1
      })
    }
```

Issue is with this fruitsCount function I guess. What may be the problem?

Comment: Can you share the full code? What is `selected`?

Comment: You say fruitsArray but you are setting an object in setCount?

Comment: Its an array of objects actually.

Comment: @skovy setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)); By selected I am randomly displaying a fruit name on another button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some full context missing, but here is one approach for the code you provided.

It will render something like this:

[image]

```
var fruitsArray = [
  { fruit: "Apple", count: 0 },
  { fruit: "Banana", count: 0 },
  { fruit: "Grapes", count: 0 }
];

function App() {
  const [fruits, setCount] = React.useState(fruitsArray);

  const updateCount = index => {
    setCount(
      fruits.map((fruit, i) => {
        if (index === i) {
          // Create a new object to avoid mutating anything in state
          return {
            ...fruit,
            count: fruit.count + 1
          };
        } else {
          // Reuse the existing fruit object since it didn't change
          return fruit;
        }
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {fruits.map((fruit, index) => (
        <button key={fruit.fruit} onClick={() => updateCount(index)}>
          {fruit.fruit}: {fruit.count}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Actually in the render method, I am not using map so I cannot pass the reference of index to updateCount function

Comment: `return (
    
        <div>
          <div>{fruitArray[selected].fruit}</div>
          <div>has {fruitArray[selected].count} votes</div>
          <br/>
          <button onClick={fruitCount}>Count</button>
          <button onClick={nextFruit}>Next fruit</button>
        </div>
      )`

Comment: If you're using `setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)); ` . like you said above, use the return value of that?

Comment: That's a separate function which I am using to randomly display quotes

Comment: const nextFruit = () => {
        setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3));
  
    }

Comment: I made this. You can see all my code here. https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-snowflake-ric3x

Comment: What kind of problem do you have? Your codesanbox seems to be working.

Comment: Then I think you should take an action if this answer helped you.